# How to connect three NSTableview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

i'm a little bit challenged. I have three nstableviews (which are called Ord, Pred, Succ, cell based) in a view. I want to fill two of my three tables ( Pred, Succ) with data when i click on a specific row of my first table(Ord).Another thing is that each time a new row is clicked it should clear clear the two tables before showing the new data. The data which will be filled is in a method fillSucc. I created for the two other tables a model for each one and an arraycontroller and bind them so i can manipulate the model more easily. But now i'm stucked, i don't know what to do now.

First the Succ Table Model
    #import

```
@interface Succ : NSObject
{
NSString* check;
NSString* numero;
NSString* designation;
NSString* durpr;
NSString* debtot;
NSString* lien;
NSString* decal;
NSString* mgt;
NSString* debavtache;
}
 @property (copy) NSString* check,*numero, *designation, *durpr, *debtot,*lien,*decal, *mgt,*devavtache;
@end
```

The model for  Pred Table:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Pred: NSObject
{
NSString* check;
NSString* numero;
NSString* designation;
NSString* durpr;
NSString* debtot;
NSString* lien;
NSString* decal;
}
 @property (copy) NSString* check,*numero, *designation, *durpr, *debtot,*lien,*decal;
@end
```

Everything else works, i just don't know how to implement this. I'm trying since 4 hours to solve this problem but it's hard and i'm walking in circles.

Comment: How is the data in Pred and Succ related to Ord? What is the question?

Comment: Pred and Succ have the same numero,designation, lien and decal as Ord. The rest is completly different and must be calculated.

Comment: Set the content of the arraycontrollers of Pred and Succ in/after `fillSucc`. Or bind the content of the arraycontrollers to properties and set the properties in/after `fillSucc`.

Comment: Thank you very much Willeke,it worked! Thank you very very much!

Answer (score -1):

Your delegate methods and datasource methods should check if the tableView from the methods == the specific table you want to manipulate. pseudo code example: `() cellForRowAtIndexPath() { if tableView == Ord {.. do Ord stuff} else if tableView == Pred {.. do Pred stuff} }` etc. Then apply similar logic to all your tableview delegate and datasource methods!

Comment: You missed "arraycontroller and bind them" in the question.